# update html content automatically

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a temp.php file which gives output in json format:

```
[{"Date":"2016-10-25 16:12:30","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2016-10-25 16:24:05","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:04:04","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:05:34","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:25:50","Temp":"0.00"}]
```

I want to load all date and temp values into a webpage. For that, the code I have written is:

```
<div id ="output"> text replaced </div>
$.ajax({
url:'temp.php',
data : " ",
dataType:'json'
success:function(data)
 {
   var date = data[0];
   var tempval = data[1];
$('#output').html("<b> DATE:</b>"+date+"<b> TEMPER: </b>"+tempval)
 }
```

But I am getting output as object, what is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access like below

```
data[0].Date   // 2016-10-25 16:12:30
data[0].Temp   // 1.0
```

OR

```
data[0]['Date']   // 2016-10-25 16:12:30
data[0]['Temp']   // 1.0
```

**For Example :**

```js
var data= [{"Date":"2016-10-25 16:12:30","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2016-10-25 16:24:05","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:04:04","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:05:34","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:25:50","Temp":"0.00"}]

console.log(data[0].Date);
console.log(data[0].Temp);
console.log(data[0]['Date']);
console.log(data[0]['Temp'])
```

The way you are accessing

> ```
> success:function(data)
>  {
>    var date = data[0];
>    var tempval = data[1];
> $('#output').html("<b> DATE:</b>"+date+"<b> TEMPER: </b>"+tempval)
>  }
> ```

**date will be**

```
date  = {"Date":"2016-10-25 16:12:30","Temp":"1.00"};
                        ^
                    This is object inside {}
```

**tempval will be**

```
tempval = {"Date":"2016-10-25 16:24:05","Temp":"1.00"};
                        ^
                    This is object inside {}
```

Thus you get below

> But I am getting output as , object object

**For comment**

> But this gives data of only first row. I want all
>   the dates and temp values. What needs to be done?

```js
var data= [{"Date":"2016-10-25 16:12:30","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2016-10-25 16:24:05","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:04:04","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:05:34","Temp":"1.00"},{"Date":"2017-02-25 23:25:50","Temp":"0.00"}];

$.each( data, function(index,item){ 
$('#output').append("<b> DATE:</b>"+item.Date+"<b> TEMPER: </b>"+item.Temp+"<br>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this gives data of only first row. I want all the dates and temp values. What needs to be done?

Comment: Thank you.Sorry for the delay in reply.

Comment: Can you say how to print the latest entry only? i.e the one with temp value 0.00

Comment: @sam: use `data[data.length-1].Temp`